# Carthage Build works but Carthage Update fails with: "Dependency xxx has no shared framework schemes"

Tags: xcode, carthage

I am trying to add Carthage support for an existing Cocoapods framework.
Seeing as `carthage build` was successful, as well as the fact that the target scheme is marked as shared, I don't know why `carthage update` is failing.

I have tried looking at the `carthage update` source code (which seems to run `carthage build` internally, making me even more perplexed), but I have not been able to find the cause of the problem.

Running `carthage build` in the framework directory seems to work:

```sh
carthage build --no-skip-current --platform ios
*** xcodebuild output can be found in [...]
*** Building scheme "xxx" in xxx.xcworkspace
```

However, when I try to integrate this into my project using `carthage update`, I get the following error:

```sh
carthage update
*** Fetching xxx
*** Checking out xxx at [...]
*** xcodebuild output can be found in [...]
*** Skipped building xxx due to the error:
Dependency "xxx" has no shared framework schemes
```

#### Note

One thing that I am unsure about is that I have a symlink (`_Pods.xcodeproj` to `Examples/Pods/xxx.xcodeproj`) to the .xcodeproj folder to allow the shared scheme to be discovered. The `Examples/Pods/xxx.xcodeproj` folder only becomes available after a `pod install` to generate the `/Example/Pods` folder.

Here is the framework directory structure:

- **_Pods.xcodeproj** (symlink to /Example/Pods/xxx.xcodeproj)
- xxx (framework name)
- Example

  - build
  - xxx (framework name)
  - Pods (created from `pod install`)

    - **xxx.xcodeproj**
    - xxx.xcworkspace
- Carthage (created from `carthage build --no-skip-current`)

  - Build

    - iOS

      - **xxx.framework** (Cannot get this to be built in project using `carthage update)

Here is my project's Cartfile:

```sh
git "local/path/to/above/framework/directory" "master"
```

Thanks